# Delete a database and its service

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm assigned the task of deleting some databases from some server.

Deleting a database is easy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177419.aspx

Seems like there is one service for each database in control panel>administrative tools>services

How can I remove those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are referring to instances.

You can just use add/remove programs and select SQL Server 2005. It will give you a list of instances you can select to delete/uninstall.

Comment: Yes, seems to be the correct path. Now if only MS wouldn't scare me with dialog window after dialog window stating that I'm removing sql server and not only one instance .. :)

Guess I'll think twice and make sure that everything is really backed up before I finally do this.